# How to do something on :odd a X amount of times?

Tags: jquery

I am adding css code to some elements using the :odd selector, however, I would only like to do this to the first 5 matches. Is there a way to limit the amount of times the :odd triggers the action before stopping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, use `:lt(5)`. This means only select the first five (0-4) odd elements.

For example: `$('li:odd:lt(5)').css('background','red');`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/23szL/)**

See: http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

Answer (score 2):

Here is your selector:

```
$(".yourclass:odd:lt(5)").show();
```